# Numeric Filter - need it to accept decimal point?

Tags: filter, textbox, decimal, point, numeric

I lifted a Numeric Filter from here,

but it isn't quite what I need, it will not allow the input of a single Decimal point,

This filter looks like this

```
DocumentFilter numericFilter = new DocumentFilter(){   

        @Override
        public void insertString(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset,
                String string, AttributeSet attr)
                throws BadLocationException {
            fb.insertString(offset, string.replaceAll("[^\\d]", ""), attr);
        }

        @Override
        public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length,
                String text, AttributeSet attrs)
                throws BadLocationException {

            fb.replace(offset, length, text.replaceAll("[^\\d]", ""), attrs);
        }
    };
```

How can I alter this so it will allow the single inclusion of a decimal point?

thanks,

Phil

Comment: I've added a single '.' to the Regex but it does allow for multiple decimals?

Comment: Ok Im doing something wrong here but with no replies I cannot solve, Ive tried multiple examples of RegEx that purport to restric 2 decimal places and none work, in fact most prevent me from entering any numbers at all. Im totally stuck here . . . . .